# How to prevent OT (transfer orders) message from generating in JDE system or how to hide them?

Tags: jde

How to prevent OT (transfer orders) message from generating in JDE system or how to hide them?
Is it in the supply demand inclusion rules options?

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind the transfer order is to emit the transfer document (ST) and then do the receipt later when the branch has received the items (OT). If you dont want the OT, then you shouln't use an ST as your transaction document. You should use an IT - Item Transfer which is accounted right away and creates no purchase document.

A good place to start with is the oracle documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31039_02/jded/html/docset.html

There is a guide for inventory management :
JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Inventory Management 8.12 Implementation Guide

Read page 124 of the PDF.